# cannot bind values to dynamic textbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i cannot bind values to dynamic textbox it will change all the values if i change any textbox value, please help because i'm stuck here from 3 days. I'm sharing what i have done

JQUERY

```
function bindAutoComplete(classname) {
    $("." + classname).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.PartNumber, value: item.PartNumber };
                            }))
                        }
                        else {
                            response([{ label: 'No results found.' }]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        },
    });

}

function bindData(element) {
    var errormsg = "";
    var amount = element.val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetPart',
        data: { 'term': amount },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#Manufacturer').val(data[1].Manufacturer);
                    $('#DateCode').val(data[0].DateCode);
                    $('#Package').val(data[0].PackageCase);
                    $('.buyingprice').val(data[0].Price);

                }
                else {
                    $('#Manufacturer').val('');
                    $('#DateCode').val('');
                    $('#Package').val('');
                    $('.buyingprice').val('');
                }
            }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            $('#error').html(jqXHR)
        }
    });
};

// fetch part number
$(document).ready(function () {
    bindAutoComplete('inputs');
    $("#maintable").on('keyup', '.inputs', function () {
        bindData($(this));
    });

});
$("#AddMore").click(function () {

    $("#maintable").each(function () {

        var tds = '<tr>';

        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';

        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {

            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
            $("#delete").fadeIn('200');
        }
        else {
            $(this).append(tds);
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="maintable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Part No
            </th>
            <th>
                BP
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="inputs" type="text" name="abcd" id="PartNumber23" style="width:130px;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="buyingprice text-box single-line" id="BuyingPrice" name="BuyingPrice" type="text" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

it change all BP dynamic textbox value if i change one BP textbox value but i want to bind different values every time on BP textbox based on autocomplete result.
please please guide me

Comment: can you may add a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Dwza yes please check this http://jsfiddle.net/FuSwn/4/

Comment: @Dwza how i can solve this?

Comment: im looking for this... just give me a moment :D

Comment: i don't see the problem... could you specify your question a little bit more ? (szenario)

Comment: @Dwza sure, i have a autocomplete on every dynamic textbox which has class "inputs" i want to bind the result of that autocomplete into BP textbox it is working on static textbox but not working on dynamic textboxes, when i change any of the BP textbox value all BP textboxes values will be changed. this is the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55111/discussion-between-usama-sheikh-and-dwza).