# cannot add ID to dynamic textbox jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm trying to add id to the dynamic textbox but i cannot do  that, i'm sharing what i have done

JQUERY

```
$("#AddMore").click(function () {

    $("#maintable").each(function () {

        var tds = '<tr>';

        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';

        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {

            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
            $("#delete").fadeIn('200');
        }
        else {
            $(this).append(tds);
            bindAutoComplete('inputs');
        }
    });

});
```

Each time it is creating a row with textboxes but i want to add id to all textboxes each time.
Please guide me

Comment: @Illaya can u see this please http://jsfiddle.net/FuSwn/4/ this is the actual problem

Comment: @Illaya and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053995/cannot-bind-values-to-dynamic-textbox

Comment: @Illaya is there any luck bro?